# the height of aspxpopup control didn't change after aspxgridview perform filtering

Tags: c#, asp.net, aspxgridview, asp.net-webcontrol

put the aspxgridview into aspxpopup control. when peform filter on the aspxgridview the row will be decrease but the height of the aspxpopup 's window does not change and it will leave blank on the bottom. any solution here? or this is bug?

Comment: is this issue browser specific?

Comment: what do you mean by aspxpopup ? is it popup exender control or window opened using window.open?

Comment: Represents a web control, which enables you to add the functionality of popup windows to your web application.
u can get more detail in http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/clsDevExpressWebASPxPopupControlASPxPopupControltopic

Answer (score -1, accepted):

IT seems to be an old issue

http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q232077.aspx

which is resolved

http://www.pageresource.com/jscript/jscreen.htm

see the links.

Comment: The problem is not about the screen resolution. But is the popup's window didn't change the height, after gridview perform filter. The gridview is in the popup.

Comment: I think this can be achieved using model popup extender ajax control. If you still don't get that better you can fix the width height of control and give scrolling after filter , we do this.

Comment: In my case i must use aspxpopup control...My boss do not want to have scrollbar. Fix the size of the control doesn't work this is because the size of the control is base on the size of its content ..... the problem is after fillter the size of the aspxgridview become shorter but the size of the popup control didn't changes....